# Save as data and return value typed in input by function

Tags: javascript, validation, input, scaledrone

```
const CHANNEL_ID = 'qqxtR1YAPcD40c4W';
const drone = new ScaleDrone(CHANNEL_ID, {
 data: { // Will be sent out as clientData via events
   name: getName(), // undefined
   color: getRandomColor(),
 }
});
```

```
function getName(){
  var userName = document.getElementById("typeUserName");
  userName.addEventListener("keypress", (event) => {
    if(event.key === "Enter"){
       event.preventDefault();  
       userName = userName.value;
       console.log(userName)
    }
    return userName;
    });
}
```

```
function createMemberElement(member) {
  const { name, color } = member.clientData;
  const el = document.createElement('div');
  el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
  el.className = 'member';
  el.style.color = color;
  return el;
}
```

Hello, what I am trying to do here is make the function return the value typed in input once Enter is pressed and the value should be saved in drone's data, yet I keep getting undefined. Data is being defined right after loading the page so maybe that's causing the issue?

Comment: The `getName()` function has no `return` statement. The event handler cannot return a value for `getName()`.

Answer (score 0):

In the `getName()` function, put the `return userName` at the very end of the function instead of inside of the `addEventListener()` function